# How to load array into datagridview in c# the right way?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to load an `array` into `datagridview` , array is being populated by reading a `csv file`. Everything works fine, but I am a bit confused about how I can break the array further and load each individual value inside a cell ?
Right now its loading an entire line into one cell, so what will be the right way to further break the array and save each individual value into a cell ?

**this is the code I am working with :**

```
public void Load()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Accounts.csv"))
            {
                string strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] result = strResult.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            }
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Account#", "Account#");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Passwor", "Password");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Server", "Server");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, result[i] });
            }

        }
```

**This is the output I am getting :**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9v4b.png)

**And this is how the CSV file looks like :**

```
Account#;Password;Server
2104373470;um3skuu;Rsptrsd
2104373472;uar1kgh;2jvatkf 
2104373475;6xuvtdp;ppjw5cj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   change your code accordingly below.
     dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add ();
                dataGridView1.Rows [i].Cells ["Account"].Value = result[i].Split(';')[0];
  dataGridView1.Rows [i].Cells ["Password"].Value = result[i].Split(';')[1];
  dataGridView1.Rows [i].Cells ["Server"].Value = result[i].Split(';')[2];
                 }
```

Comment: Hi @senthikumar2185  I tried that but it throws error "`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataGridViewRow'`"

Comment: @M_Arad sorry i changed the code now check and confirm